# htaccess rewrite losing $_GET on second rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

Here are my two rewrites:

```
RewriteRule folder/(.*)/$ /folder/subfolder/index.php?s=$1
RewriteRule folder/(.*)/review/$ /folder/subfolder/review.php?s=$1
```

The first rewrite works perfectly, for example:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/hello/
```

But the second:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/hello/review/
```

It doesn't pass the "hello" as the $_GET over.

Why is the second rewrite losing its parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's reading (.*) to include "...site.com/folder/**hello/review/**" which then doesn't match any rewrite rule.
Change the rewrite rule to:

RewriteRule folder/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/review/$ /folder/subfolder/review.php?s=$1

That will limit it to alpha-numeric and "-" characters only.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it is missing the $_GET now and is opening the index.php instead of review.php

Comment: replace the ([\w\n\-]+) with ([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) Sorry, I didn't really have a way to test it. Here is a good cheat sheet for regular expressions. http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/

Comment: Put the more complex on top. If it's matching the first it won't move on to the second.